Blazor Web App Call .NET methods from JavaScript not work in .NET 8
My attempts to run a NET call from JS ended in failure.
Tried including examples from Microsoft.
But adding to the page
@rendermode InteractiveServer

So that the button would work. Causes an error.
Here is the code that worked in .NET 7
async Task Up()
{
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("Crop.responses", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), Id);
   crop2View = "opcity-0";
}

[JSInvokable]
public async void ResponseMethod(string data)
{
    model.Base64 = data;
    await UploadServer();
    StateHasChanged();
}

JS code
var base64data;

window.Crop = {        
    responses: function (component, id) {
        resize.result('blob').then(function (blob) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onloadend = async function () {
                base64data = reader.result;
                var i = document.getElementById('result-' + id);
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = base64data;
                i.appendChild(img);
                return component.invokeMethodAsync('ResponseMethod', base64data);
            }
        });

    }
};

How to call ResponseMethod from JS

Hi, about how to call js from .net and how to call .net method from js doesn't have much change between .net 7 and .net 8. I had a test with your codes(comment some parts of your codes) and all the methods can  be called successfully. So that I'm afraid the issue you faced is due to that you didn't migrate your .net 7 blazor server app to .net 8 blazor web app. Please see this guidance.

Updated from OP: The problem was that I tried to send more than 32 kb. So that I could receive it. The message size is the key point we need to pay attention to which causing the issue.
========================================

So that the button would work. Causes an error.

I had a test with your codes in a new blazor web app server side rendered application which worked well. So that I'm afraid it's due to missing some configuartion during migrating from .Net 7 to .Net 8. Please note there's no blazor server in .Net 8 anymore(Blazor Server is supported), we have blazor webapp instead.

@inject IJSRuntime JS
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<p>
    <button @onclick="Up">Up</button>
</p>
<p>
    @crop2View + @Base64string
</p>

@code {
   private string crop2View = "init";
   private string Base64string = "init base 64";

   async Task Up()
   {
       await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("Crop.responses", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), "id1");
       crop2View = "opcity-0";
   }

   [JSInvokable]
   public async void ResponseMethod(string data)
   {
       Base64string = data;
       // await UploadServer();
       StateHasChanged();
   }
}

//put the script just behind the <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script> in App.razor
<script>
    window.Crop = {
        responses: function (component, id) {
            alert(1);
            // resize.result('blob').then(function (blob) {
            //     var reader = new FileReader();
            //     reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            //     reader.onloadend = async function () {
            //         base64data = reader.result;
            //         var i = document.getElementById('result-' + id);
            //         var img = document.createElement('img');
            //         img.src = base64data;
            //         i.appendChild(img);
                    return component.invokeMethodAsync('ResponseMethod', "new base 64 data");
            //     }
            // });

        }
    };
</script>



Please add to your answer that you need to watch the message size. The problem was that I tried to send more than 32 kb. So that I could receive it.

Thanks a lot for your kind sharing @blakcat, I already updated my post.
